# Modify while loop to execute at-least once

Tags: java, loops

doing some exam revision. One question is, Modifiy code to so that the loop will execute at-least once.

My Code :

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10) {
   if (x % 2 != 0) {
       System.out.println(x);
   }
   x++;
}
```

Now i know while will loop while the condition is true, i know i cannot remove the x++ as this will give me infinite zeros. i think i would just remove the if statement and the brace related to it.

would you agree?

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10) {
    System.out.println(x);
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Look into a `do-while` loop.

Comment: You've changed the output -- are you sure that's allowed?

Comment: That `if` statement only prints the odd numbers, so removing it would change the desired output.

Comment: i have updated the main question with do -while , i will have to mess about with it to get it working, its only revision tho

Comment: You have changed the while condition, and you wonder why your output is different?

Comment: Your revision won't print anything more than 0 because it first prints r, then while `r % 2 != && r < 10` is true, iterates r (which will only happen once).

Answer (score 2):

Although this specific loop actually executes at least once even unchanged, that is not a property of a while-loop.

If the condition in the while-loop is not met, the loop never executes.

A do-while loop works almost the same way, except the condition is evaluated after execution of the loop, hence, the loop always executes at least once:

```
void Foo(bool someCondition)
{
    while (someCondition)
    {
        // code here is never executed if someCondition is FALSE
    }
}
```

on the other hand:

```
void Foo(bool someCondition)
{
    do 
    {
        // code here is executed whatever the value of someCondition
    }
    while (someCondition) // but the loop is only executed *again* if someCondition is TRUE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not agree, that would change the fundamental purpose of the loop (to emit every other number to stdout).

Look into converting to the do/while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst your solution has technically answered the question, I don't think it's what they were looking for (which isn't really your fault, and makes it a badly-worded question in my opinion). Given it's an exam question, I think what they're after here is a `do while` loop.

It works the same as a `while` loop except that the `while` condition is checked at the end of the loop - which means that it will always execute at least once.

---

**Example:**

```
while(condition){
    foo();
}
```

Here, `condition` is checked first, and then if `condition` is `true`, the loop is executed, and `foo()` is called.

Whereas here:

```
do{
    foo();
}while(condition)
```

the loop is executed once, `foo()` is called, and then `condition` is checked to know whether to execute the loop again.

---

**More:**

For further reading you might want to check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) or [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) tutorial on `while`, `do while` and `for` loops.

Answer (score -1):

```
int x = 0;
        while (x <10){
        System.out.println(x);
            x++;
        }
```

Will work

EDIT: i think the others comments are rights too, the do/while loop will force one execution of the code

Answer (score -1):

```
var x = 0;
do {
    if (x % 2 != 0) System.out.println(x);
    x++;
} while (x < 10);
```

Comment: Then why on earth do you take that functionality outside the loop if you actually notice it breaks the program?

Comment: True, added the print statement to execute through the loop.  Jayseppi hasn't given what he expects the program to do, though, and thought that removing the expected functionality of the loop would solve his problem...